# Combination of EnumMap and ConcurrentHashMap in Guava?

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, thread-safety, guava

Is there a map class in Guava (or somewhere else) that provides both the features of `EnumMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap`? So I could have a thread-safe map implementation that is very fast with enum keys?

I know I can just wrap an `EnumMap` in a fully synchronized map with a call to `Collections.synchronizedMap()` but it is not full (expensive) synchronization what I am looking for.

Comment: Theoretically not very hard to implement it by yourself holding an `AtomicReference<EnumClass>[]` array...

Comment: Not built into Guava or the JDK, no, I'm afraid not.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I guess you are in the Guava team? Why this class is not there? Is it such a weird requirement? Any plan to add it in the future?

Comment: I haven't ever heard of demand for such a thing.  You're welcome to file a feature request, but it'd probably need evidence of demand before Guava added it.  Additionally, for what it's worth: `EnumMap`s generally have relatively small size, since their size is bounded by the number of enum constants of the specified type, which reduces the need for efficient concurrent implementations.

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap<K extends Enum<K>, V>` suits all these needs, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by *it is not full synchronization what I am looking for*. Please clarify.

I would wrap your `EnumMap` in a holder that implements a read/write lock on the map.

Comment: but this is close to what Collections.synchronizedMap() does, right?

Comment: @Sergio - Perhaps - but it is likely that `Collections.synchronizedMap()` synchronizes **all** access, i.e. no two threads ever get parallel access. My suggestion is to improve that by allowing multiple read requests in parallel but write access gets exclusive access. Again it depends what you mean by *it is not full synchronization what I am looking for*.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap limits contended locks. I do not know the implementation details but probably does it by locking on an object associated with a slot in the corresponding array of entries. I am looking for the same but with the performance advantages of EnumMap since my keys are enumerations.

Comment: @Sergio - Access will still be fast - the synchronized map will still access the underlying map that way.